Differnce between bash file_name and ./file_name
I created a file with li.sh in scripting
#!/bin/env bash

read -p 'What is your name' name
echo $name

while I tried to execute with using the command ./li.sh, here I received the permission denied error but when I executed with command bash li.sh, It executed without any error. Is it secured to run with bash li.sh ?
I want to know the difference between ./li.sh and bash li.sh.

That's not really a programming question, that's Linux 101 ... to be able to execute the script in the local directory without specifying bash scriptname you need to chmod it (give it execute permissions).  chmod u+x li.sh.  Voted to close.

https://superuser.com/questions/818793/my-first-linux-script-wont-run

In the first example you tried to execute the script file, which does not have execute permission, so it failed.  In the second example you executed bash, which does have execute permission, so it succeeded.

I think the reason that you are unable to run the shell script through ./li.sh is because you haven't set the file permission to executable
You could have a look at this
https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/linux-file-permissions-explained
TL;DR: you can run sudo chmod +x li.sh and then continue to proceed with ./li.sh
Assuming you are in the same directory when u run bash li.sh and ./li.sh, it should both work the same way. When you specify bash li.sh, it first runs bash and executes the file, where as when you run ./li.sh, it reads the file, sees that there is the #! symbol, it will run /bin/env bash, and then it will continue the script.

Here's the steps that happen when you run bash li.sh:

Your shell will look for bash exeecutable in your $PATH, and find it somewhere like /bin/bash.
Your shell will ask the OS to execute that program, passing li.sh as an argument
bash starts up, parses its arguments, and see that it's being asked to run li.sh.
bash will try to open the li.sh file for reading. When it does so, the operating system will confirm that your user has read permission for the the file
bash then starts interpreting ("running") the contents of the script.

Importantly, the OS has no idea what you want the file for. Once you have a file open with read permission, it doesn't know the difference between you reading to print it (e.g. cat li.sh), compress it (e.g. zip li.sh), or for any other purpose. All that matters is that you have read permission, and you do. bash just so happens to interpret it, in a way that's identical to running it directly.
Contrast this with the steps the happen when you just run ./li.sh:

Your shell will ask the OS execute the file directly
The the OS will see that it starts with a "shebang" (#!) instead of the usual 0x7F 0x45 0x4c 0x46 sequence that every Linux ELF executable executable starts with

This tells it that rather than executing the file directly, it needs to run whatever is listed in the shebang


It's parse the #!/bin/env bash shebang, and execute /bin/env, passing to it 2 arguments: bash li.sh
env will then run bash li.sh
bash will then start interpreting the script.

Since the operating system knows your express purpose for accessing the file is to execute it, your execute permission matters instead of your read permission.
